# How can I scrape elements inside the divs that i'm scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble printing the element inside a div.
so this is the tag that I want to scrape

div class="page-box house-lst-page-box" comp-module="page" page-url="/ershoufang/miyun/pg{page}" page-data="{"totalPage":73,"curPage":1}"

I want my code to print the the integer inside totalPage, which is 73.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Quick terminology note: an *element* is the combination of its *tags* and content. Inside a *tag*, you may map *attribute names* to *attribute values*. To demonstrate, you probably have reference to a `div` **element**, of which you are showing us its opening **tag** `<div ...>`, which maps the **attribute name** `page-data` to the **attribute value** `{"totalPage":73,"curPage":1}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class="page-box house-lst-page-box" comp-module="page" page-url="/ershoufang/miyun/pg{page}" page-data="{&quot;totalPage&quot;:73,&quot;curPage&quot;:1}"><a class="on" href="/ershoufang/miyun/" data-page="1">1</a><a href="/ershoufang/miyun/pg2" data-page="2">2</a><a href="/ershoufang/miyun/pg3" data-page="3">3</a><span>...</span><a href="/ershoufang/miyun/pg73" data-page="73">73</a><a href="/ershoufang/miyun/pg2" data-page="2">下一页</a></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

data = soup.select_one("div[page-data]")["page-data"]
data = json.loads(data)

print("Total page:", data["totalPage"])
```

Prints:

```
Total page: 73
```